# How to register the index where a condition is met

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to simulate a heat transfer problem using python where I want to plot a certain temperature T over the course of a certain time span. The problem would consist of three phases. In the first phase, the code should execute a certain function `func_1(t)` that depends on the current time, until the temperature reaches a certain point. After that, the code should execute a different function `func_2(t)`. When T reaches another temperature, the code should execute a function `func_3(t)` which is the same as `func_1(t)` but with a shifted timescale. So basically:

```
def func_1(x):
    y = np.exp(-x / tau) * (T_start - T_amb) + T_amb
    return y

def func():
    t = np.linspace(t0, t_end, 1 + round((t_end + t0) / dt)
    T = np.zeros(len(t))
    for i in range(len(t)):
        T[0] = T_start
        if T[i] < T1:
            T[i + 1] = func_1(t[i])
        if T[i]>= T1 and T[i] < T2:
            T[i + 1] = func_2(t[i])
        if T[i] >= T2:
            T[i + 1] = func_3(t[i])
    return T
```

This code behaves exactly as I'd expect but not as I want. T rises at first like an exponential function and when T = T1 it changes to a different function, so the first two phases work as intended. When T >= T2, I want T to act like an exponential function again where the time starts to count at the point where T = T2.
Mathematically, I want `func_1(x)` to act like e^(x) and `func_3(x)` like e^(x-a). The problem is, I need to figure out what a would be.

I could cheat a bit and run the code to find out at which index T >= T2, and then make the correction, but I want to run the code multiple times to change certain parameters. Changing these parameters will change the time it takes to meet the condition, so I would have to manually adjust it every time. I guess my question really is how I could register the index at which point a certain condition is met. Does a function already exist for this, do I have to write one myself, or am I just doing it completely wrong?

This is how it's supposed to look.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuSiK.png

Comment: `index = None; for ... if T[i] >= T2: index = i; ... return (T, index)`?

Comment: @ekhumoro This returns every index where the condition is met, with each iteration overwriting the previous value, meaning the index changes with every iteration. I just want to know which index FIRST meets the condition and use that value as a constant in the loop.

Comment: Well then simply do `if index is None: index = i`.

Answer (score 0):

This is (more or less) an implementation of ekhumoro's suggestions:

```
def func():
    t = np.linspace(t0, t_end, 1 + round((t_end + t0) / dt)
    T = np.zeros(len(t))
    t0_T2 = t0
    have_T2_transition = False
    for i in range(len(t)):
        T[0] = T_start
        if T[i] < T1:
            T[i + 1] = func_1(t[i])
        if T[i]>= T1 and T[i] < T2:
            T[i + 1] = func_2(t[i])
            if T[i + 1] >= T2 and not have_T2_transition:
                # transition!
                have_T2_transition = True
                t0_T2 = t[i]
        if T[i] >= T2:
            T[i + 1] = func_3(t[i] - t0_T2 + t0)
    return T
```

You could also just save t0_T2 as the value of t[i] at the end of either of the first two if statements.  This would capture the case where the middle temperature range is skipped.